# Private Link backed storage and source ip

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I have extended access to my storage account via Private Link backed by a private endpoint to a partner. This is how the setup looks -

1. Storage account (StAccSource) in Azure Tenant A
2. A private link service enabling a private endpoint to storage account "StAccSource" in Tenant B's VNET

The question I have is - when storage account "StAccSource" is accessed via private endpoint from Tenant B's subnet, what would be the IP address space that we will see on the storage account. Would it be the CIDR for Tenant B's VNET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a private endpoint in Tenant B's VNet for the Storage account StAccSource in Tenant A, then the private endpoint will be assigned a private IP address from the subnet in the VNet which in Tenant B. So the CIDR and IP address space of the Storage account depends on the configuration of the subnet that the private endpoint in, depends on the VNet that the subnet in.

Comment: Yep, I am aware of the IP that gets assigned to the storage account. I wanted to be sure that when the storage account is accessed via let us say - ADF from within the same VNET as the private endpoint, would the storage account see the call coming from a private IP for ADF (SHIR based).

Comment: @NitinRastogi Of course, yes. The storage account uses the private IP address of the private endpoint to access the ADF in the same VNet.

Comment: @NitinRastogi Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?